# CSS button not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I have made this button by editing "Simple Hover Effect by Vincent Durand". But the problem is that some css in my blog is overlapping. So it is not aligning to middle correctly. I cant find which one it may be. I tried using !important tag in some places. But I guess it didn't work out. What I need to know where should I use !important in this code to align the button to middle? Or will I need a new css element to do that?

```css
<!-- Awesome button css Start -->
.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-high!importantr: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn:before,.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,.btn-green:after {
background: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn:hover:before,.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
<!-- Awesome button css End -->
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin">
    <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">
        Click Here To See Answers
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Using !important to overwrite a style is a very bad habit, please post the whole code of what's overlapping with your button so we can figure out a better way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `*{box-sizing:border-box;}` to ur css

```css
<!-- Awesome button css Start -->
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-high!importantr: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn:before,.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,.btn-green:after {
background: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn:hover:before,.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
<!-- Awesome button css End -->
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin">
    <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">
        Click Here To See Answers
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to center align the button

```
.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
<!-- Awesome button css Start -->.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-high!importantr: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}

.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,
.btn-green:after {
  background: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}

<!-- Awesome button css End -->.btn-green {}
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin">
  <a class="btn btn-green" href="https://myneobuxportal.blogspot.com/p/answer-gamer-quiz-v2.html">
        Click Here To See Answers
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. But I prefered to use *{box-sizing:border-box;} as Gautam Naik suggested.

Comment: cool :) you are free to use what suits your requirement. thanks so much for acknowledging my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
add one parent div and set this div  text-align: center;
```

```css
<!-- Awesome button css Start -->
.demo{
text-align: center;
}

.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-high!importantr: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn:before,.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,.btn-green:after {
background: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn:hover:before,.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
<!-- Awesome button css End -->
```

```html
<div class="Demo">
<div class="btn-margin">
    <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">
        Click Here To See Answers
      </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to add extra div to center align the content. Simply on the wrapper div i.e. "btn-margin" add an extra style to it, "text-align:center;". Should serve the purpose of center aligning the content in the center.

Comment: this is simple way

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari I already used it in the question. It is still there. But it didn't worked. Adding another parent div to add the style did made it work.

Comment: @FuadHasan Then lets find out why it didn't work!. Problem is ".btn-margin" styles are not getting applied at all. Issue is the first line in the css "<!-- Awesome button css Start -->" . This is wrong the correct way to add css comments are "/*  ............... */". Check the following fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b4yd0wkc/3/

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Thank you so much for your help. This solves my case. This works out the best and simple way.

Comment: I suggest @HardikPrajapati not to add an additional div "Demo". There is already a div "btn-margin". Make use of it to center align the content, which was actually done but styles were not getting applied as I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was with the comment :(

I used html comment in css. That's why this happened. Thanks @CharuMaheshwari for mentioning that out. Also another thanks for other 3 answers. All of them worked.

With @CharuMaheshwari help this is the code I decided to use.

```css
/* Awesome button css Start */
.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-high!importantr: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn:before,.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,.btn-green:after {
background: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn:hover:before,.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}
/* Awesome button css End */
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin">
    <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">
        Click Here To See Answers
      </a>
</div>
```